# restricting movements to x,y,z for the handicapped

Tags: modeling, transforms, shortcut, 3d-manipulator

I know that when you want to restrict movement or scaling to a certain axis you hold down the keyboard key corrresponding to the axis that you want isolate but I have a problem I am handicapped and only can only use 1 hand to move the mouse.

Is there any other way to restrict which axis you want to operate on?

It would also help if when you select move or scale the direction arrows are displayed. It seems that the arrows become visable only occasionally. Is there any way to get them to show?

Comment: The middle mouse button can do the axis snapping while holding it in translating. I will personally recommend using Blender 2.80 since the interface is more comfortable and consistent. The Gizmo will be a lot easier for mouse only usage

Comment: Also you can press G X and then move the mouse - all with one hand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to hold down they key, just press it once. So you should be able to do it with one hand.

The arrows/gizmo appears if you select the move/rotate/scale tool from the toolshelf (top left). That should allow you to control your objects using just the mouse.

[image]

You used to be able to draw gestures to control movement too, but I think that has gone now. This add-on looks like it might help in your case, but I haven't tried it myself: [Gesture Ops](https://blendermarket.com/products/gesture-ops)

Comment: I was hoping that a single press would work but it didn't for instance if you hit the X key it still comes up as the delete dialog.

Comment: It works like you want it to, if I understand you properly, if you use the single key accelerators to initiate the action. So press 'g' to grab, then press 'x' to limit movement to the x-axis, then press 'x' again to limit to the local x-axis. Similarly, for example, press  's' then 'y' to scale in y-axis or 'r' then 'zz' to rotate about local z-axis, or whatever you want.